# django-nonrel 500 server error on Google App deployment

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I am a newbie with a problem working with Django-nonrel on Google App Engine.

I created a new app called "helloapp".

1) I have created a view in views.py called hello world:

> from django.http import HttpResponse
>
> def hello(request):
>          return HttpResponse("Hello world")

2) I have then linked to it in the urls.py using:

> from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
> from helloapp.views import hello
>
> urlpatterns = patterns('',
>          (r'^hello/$',hello),
> )

This works fine locally, but on live I am getting 500 Server error.

In the GAE logs I see that I am getting an import error 
 ImportError: No module named helloapp.views

This is confusing since, as mentioned, this works fine locally.

Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
from views import hello
```

Locally your views.py is in a helloapp directory. But when it gets uploaded onto app engine it is placed into a directory with a version number like this, where helloapp.views does not exist:

/base/data/home/apps/helloapp/1.23456789/views.py

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Can't believe I didn't try that before. :)