# URLConf that works on development server but not on GAE

Tags: django, google-app-engine, urlconf

I am using Django non-rel in Google App Engine, and my URLConf seems not to work and generate a 500 Server Error.

This is my `urls.py` file at the root of my app :

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^home/', include('appname.home.urls')),
)
```

And this is my `urls.py` in a subpackage `home` of `appname`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
urlpatterns = patterns(r'appname.home.views',
    url(r'^0/', 'home'),
)
```

It works great in development server but it does not work on Google App Engine.

I already read [a related question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348513/django-nonrel-500-server-error-on-google-app-deployment) but it did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the error message say in the logs?  You urlpatterns is malformed.  The first `r''` is incorrect.  That should be a string.  And, is the `0` in your url intentional?  Change to:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('appname.home.views',
    url(r'^$', 'home'), # matches mysite.com
    url(r'^0/$', 'home'), # matches mysite.com/0/
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have fixed this but that was not the problem apparently. I have checked the logs as you suggested and it tells me that I have forgotten to configure ALLOWED_HOSTS. Now it works.